# (LibGDX) Set actor to fixed position on TiledMap

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

How can I set an actor to an absolute / fixed position on my TiledMap, such that it does not follow the camera when I pan around?[image]

[image]

Currently my code looks like:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
rootGroup = new Group();

castleMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("castleMap.tmx");
isoMapRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(castleMap, 1/32f);

...

final FitViewport fitViewport = new FitViewport(worldWidth, worldHeight);
stage = new Stage(fitViewport);
rootGroup.setSize(stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
stage.addActor(rootGroup);

barracks = new Barracks(barracksIcon, self);
rootGroup.addActor(barracks);
```

From there, whether I try to position the barracks actor using

```
barracks.setPosition(x, y);
```

or using

```
Vector2 vector = new Vector2(x, y);
vector = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(vector);
vector = rootGroup.stageToLocalCoordinates(vector);
barracks.setPosition(vector.x, vector.y);
```

I get the same result.

I emphatically do not want to use Tables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems too silly to be correct, but I achieved the desired result with the following:

In the method that handles the camera moving...

```
stage.addListener(new DragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float screenX, float screenY, int pointer) {
            final float x = Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * .05f;
            final float y = Gdx.input.getDeltaY() * .05f;

            camera.translate(-x,y);
            camera.update();

            final float destinationX = rootGroup.getX() + x;
            final float destinationY = rootGroup.getY() - y;

            rootGroup.setPosition(destinationX, destinationY);
            stage.act();
            stage.draw();
        }
    });
```

Rather than "setting" the object (or in this case, it's parent Group()) to a fixed position on the map, I dynamically move the entire group relative to the camera in real-time.